# Node/Express Fatal error parsing 7000 xml documents

Tags: javascript, node.js, xml, loops, express

My server downloads a text file (around 800 mb), which is really XML strings appended to one another. After splitting this string into an array of valid XML strings, I loop through this array and use a library to convert it into JSON, where I then grab the relevant data and add it into my database.

The problem is, there are around 7000 XML strings (indices), and my application errors with this message:

```
FATAL ERROR: Ineffective mark-compacts near heap limit Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory
```

I have tried to increase the `--max_old_space_size=4096` in my package.json file. This improved it, failing out at around the 6000th index. I then tried doubling it to 8192, which also failed.

**Does anyone know of a solution to this?**

---

*Other Information*

The reason I need this data:

My application includes users who can create textual search conditions. Once a week, the server downloads this file, and based on user search conditions, an email will be sent which includes the documents that have matched these search conditions.

Do I need to load these documents into the database? I'm planning on cleaning out the tables after the emails are sent anyway. I chose to try it this way because I thought that leveraging inner joins and such would be faster than doing everything in plain js.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are other limitations apart from the general memory usage. Specifically there are limitations on object size.

I would suggest using streams to avoid loading the entire file into memory. How do you download the file? For instance, you can pipe a wget process into a [transform stream](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_class_stream_transform). You can implement a _transform method for your transform stream and get it to do the following "splitting".

> After splitting this string into an array of valid XML strings

You can then parse the XML data or use another Transform or Writable stream.

Code:

```
const { Transform } = require('stream');

const parseXMLString = new Transform({
  transform(chunk, encoding, callback) {
    const xml_parts = ...// Identify XML
    // Other operations
    callback(null, parsed_chunk);
  }
});

const wget = require('child_process').spawn('wget', ['-qO-', myfileurl]);
wget.stdout.pipe(parseXMLString).pipe(...); // Pipe into writable stream
```

Alternatively you can get the file locally:

```
const file_stream = require('fs').createReadStream(filename);
file_stream.pipe(parseXMLString);
```

Or if it is zipped:

```
const unzip = require('child_process').spawn('unzip', ['-c', filename]);
unzip.stdout.pipe(parseXMLString);
```

Comment: The file is a zip file from the internet that I used axios to download. I then use adm-zip to unzip the file, and then use their inbuilt 'getData()' function to get the xml string. `var xml = zipEntry.getData().toString("utf8");` Is it possible to use wget on a local file? can I use the .toString() method on a chunk? Thanks!

Comment: You can unzip or stream the file directly into node with fs.createReadStream(file). I've added examples in my answer. Just to note that I'm not 100% sure if unzip streams to stdout so better check that.

Comment: Awesome. Thanks for the information, I'm going to have a closer read of the Node.js docs!